# Missing Left Parenthesis Error - Creating Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a bit confused where my missing left parenthesis is coming into play (ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis). Any suggestions? Below is an example of similar syntax with obvious test names. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
CREATE TABLE rosters (
        rosterid    NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
        playerid    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
        teamid      NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
        seasonid    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_player FOREIGN KEY playerid REFERENCES players(playerid),
CONSTRAINT fk_team FOREIGN KEY teamid REFERENCES teams(teamid),
CONSTRAINT fk_season FOREIGN KEY seasonid REFERENCES season(seasonid);
```

Comment: Where is the closing parenthesis for rosters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems fairly self-explanatory... you need the FK column name(s) to be in parentheses, [as shown in the syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE__CJADJGEC):

```
CREATE TABLE rosters (
        rosterid    NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
        playerid    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
        teamid      NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
        seasonid    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_player FOREIGN KEY (playerid) REFERENCES players(playerid),
--                               ^        ^
CONSTRAINT fk_team FOREIGN KEY (teamid) REFERENCES teams(teamid),
--                             ^      ^
CONSTRAINT fk_season FOREIGN KEY (seasonid) REFERENCES season(seasonid));
--                               ^        ^                            ^
```

I've added the missing closing parenthesis for the overall statement too.

Quick demo with made-up referenced tables:

```
CREATE TABLE players (playerid number(5) PRIMARY KEY);

Table PLAYERS created.

CREATE TABLE teams (teamid number(5) PRIMARY KEY);

Table TEAMS created.

CREATE TABLE season (seasonid number(5) PRIMARY KEY);

Table TEAMS created.

CREATE TABLE rosters (
        rosterid    NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
        playerid    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
        teamid      NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
        seasonid    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_player FOREIGN KEY (playerid) REFERENCES players(playerid),
CONSTRAINT fk_team FOREIGN KEY (teamid) REFERENCES teams(teamid),
CONSTRAINT fk_season FOREIGN KEY (seasonid) REFERENCES season(seasonid));

Table ROSTERS created.
```

Comment: Thanks!  Ugh...  I thought I had tried that but I removed them.  Either way, thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a right parenthesis after season(seasonId).